# Group By Count Objects

Tags: c#, linq

I want to count the number of items I grouped. I have a list with type Liquidity Builder:

```
public class LiquidityBuilder
{
private string _lp;
private string _timezone;
private int _size;
private bool _ask;

public string LP
{
    get { return _lp; }
}

public int Size
{
    get { return _size; }
}

public string Timezone
{
    get { return _timezone; }
}

public bool Ask
{
    get { return _ask; }
}

public LiquidityBuilder(string lp, string timezone, int size, bool ask)
{
    _lp = lp;
    _timezone = timezone;
    _size = size;
    _ask = ask;
}
}
```

Data looks something like this:

```
LP      Timezone      Size     Ask
GS       LDN        1000000  True
GS       LDN        3000000  True
GS       TOR        2000000  True
JPM      TOR        1000000  False
CS       ASIA       1000000  True
JPM      TOR        1000000  False
CITI     TOR        2000000  False
```

I need the count the groups with keys LP, Timezone and Size, so for example
GS LDN True --> Count: 2

Here's what I have:

```
var result = liquidtyTimezoneData.GroupBy(x => new { x.LP, x.Timezone, x.Ask })
                         .Select(x => new
                         {
                             LP = x.Key.LP,
                             Timezone = x.Key.Timezone,
                             Ask = x.Key.Ask,
                             Sum = x.Sum(z => z.Size)
                         });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: x.Key.Count() should do the trick i think

Comment: *Welcome to StackOverflow!* Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not", please try to find a more meaningful title for your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `x.Count()` to get the count of items in the group.

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
var result = liquidtyTimezoneData.GroupBy(x => new { x.LP, x.Timezone, x.Ask });
        foreach (var r in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("LP: {0} TZ: {1} Ask: {2} Count: {3}", r.Key.LP, r.Key.Timezone, r.Key.Ask, r.Count());
        }
```